# CakePHP query - Unexpected big delay

Tags: mysql, cakephp

It annoys me that the following query when fired up by an AJAX request takes 1 second to process where as when called during page refresh(synchronous) takes merely 2 ms. I have spent hours tracking down what goes wrong but I am helpless. I have tried Model->read, Model->find, Model->query() yet it takes the same amount of time. I think 1 second for a simple query like this is not natural. May be the CakePHP models wasting too much resources and time. But my instincts say it's related to query cache.

```
protected function _user_info($id= NULL){
            //benchmarking
    $time = -microtime(true);

    if(!$id){
        if($this->Auth->loggedIn())
            $id = $this->Auth->user('id');
        else
            return NULL;
    }
    $this->loadModel('User');
    /*$findOptions = array('conditions'=>array('User.id'=>$id),
        'fields'=>'User.id, User.name, User.email, User.role, dp',
        'limit'=>1,
        'recursive'=>-1);
    $r = $this->User->find('first', $findOptions);
    */
    $r = $this->User->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$id."' LIMIT 1");
    $time += microtime(true);
    echo '<h1>'.$time.'</h1>';       //out- time taken for the query
    return $r['User'];
}
```

Any kind of help would be awesome!

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `query()` - use `find()` instead.

Comment: Your benchmarking goes over several lines. You should narrow it down so you know exactly which line is taking a long time.

Comment: @joshua.paling -I have tried everything benchmarking every single line and then in groups! It's either `find()` or `query()` that takes a second to process all the time.

Comment: Hmm, not sure then. The only way to take it further would be to add your benchmarking stuff in the relevant methods in /lib/Cake/Model/Model.php to narrow it down further.

Comment: `WHERE id = '".$id."' LIMIT 1` ugh, no matter if it's just for testing purposes, such code should never see the light of the day.

Comment: Are you on debug(0) when you test?

Comment: @user221931 -No I'm on debug(2)

Comment: @ndm -Suggest a better way to write the same piece of code?

Comment: `WHERE id = '" . (int)$id . "' LIMIT 1` or `WHERE id = '" . $this->User->getDataSource()->value($id) . "' LIMIT 1` ... **http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#model-query**

Answer (score 0):

First, try normal Cake search style:

```
// You should have containable
$this->User->contain();
$r = $this->User->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('id'=>$id)));
```

Test it.
Cheers.

Comment: You should elaborate on your answer a bit more explaining why this is the "normal Cake search style" and maybe provide some more info e.g. from the documentation.

Comment: If you read doc, you will see, why this is cake search style. You will not see this code too often in doc : $this->User->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '".$id."' LIMIT 1");

Answer (score 0):

If you're on `debug` 2 you're not counting execution times but debugging overhead also.

With debug enabled cache won't be used for long which will mean the DB will be asked to DESCRIBE the table, an sql log will be created, expensive object reflection might be requested multiple times especially if you hit warnings, exceptions or non fatal errors and all this will take *considerably* longer.